# DHCP error when creating a kvm ubuntu image

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to create a new ubuntu image in kvm using Virtual Machine Manager.
I select "CDROM" ad the installation media and insert an Ubuntu CD into the drive.
When I hit "Create" the newly created virtual machine boots from CD and proceeds with the Ubuntu installation program.
I get stuck on the "Configure the network step". I get an error message:
"Network authentication failed. Your network is probably not using the DHCP protocol. Alternatively, the DHCP server may be slow or some network hardware is not working correctly".

Note that I have executed that step successfully in the past many times.

What could have possibly happened? Did my Virtual Machine Manager Configuration somehow get messed up?

Answer (score 0):

You say that you have "executed that step many times", but was it on the same VM Host ?  Is it possible that for this virtual host you have not configured the NIC correctly and/or your host is not correctly configured to act as a router with DHCP server or as a bridge ?

In order to find the solution maybe you should do a tcpdump on the appropriate virtual interface on the host and see if it is receiving DHCP requests and sending responses as a first port of call.

Comment: I have executed that step on the same physical host usign the same KVM virtual machine manager. Whenever I create a new VM I select that it use Virtual NATed interface. I never had to configure anything special on mu host machine. I could be wrong but I thought it would be the virtual machine manager's job to handle DHCP for the guest.

Comment: All of a sudden it's working again. Not even sure what I did. Maybe it was the reboot. My gut feeling tells me I'm going to have this problem again very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting libvirtd using `systemctl stop libvirtd` followed by `systemctl start libvirtd`